# Moving the camera

Tags: c++, camera, projection, direct3d

I created a camera which is a LookAt camera. I do move it around by changing the position and the target position at the same time. I also added a rotation value for every axis and this is how the get Matrix looks like:

```
Camera::Camera() : m_pos(XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)), m_target(XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)), m_upVec(XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f)), m_rotation(XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f))
{
}

Camera::Camera(XMFLOAT3 position, XMFLOAT3 target) : m_pos(position), m_target(target), m_upVec(XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f))
{

}
Camera::~Camera()
{
}

XMMATRIX Camera::getViewMatrix()
{
    XMMATRIX lookAt = XMMatrixLookAtLH(XMLoadFloat3(&m_pos), XMLoadFloat3(&m_target), XMLoadFloat3(&m_upVec));
    //XMMATRIX translation = XMMatrixTranslation(m_pos.x, m_pos.y, m_pos.z); //tryed adding this
    XMMATRIX rotationX = XMMatrixRotationX(m_rotation.x);
    XMMATRIX rotationY = XMMatrixRotationY(m_rotation.y);
    XMMATRIX rotationZ = XMMatrixRotationZ(m_rotation.z);
    return lookAt * rotationX * rotationY * rotationZ;
}

void Camera::setPos(XMFLOAT3 pos, XMFLOAT3 target)
{
    m_target = target;
    m_pos = pos;
}

void Camera::setRotation(XMFLOAT3 rot)
{
    m_rotation = rot;
}

XMFLOAT3 Camera::getPosition()
{
    return m_pos;
}

XMFLOAT3 Camera::getRotation()
{
    return m_rotation;
}

XMFLOAT3 Camera::getTarget()
{
    return m_target;
}
```

I am trying to move the camera depending on it's position but it always moves along the axis. Not in "it's coordinate system".

Here is an example for movement and rotation:

```
if (m_keyBoardKeys[DIK_UP] & 0x80)
{
    m_camera->setPos(XMFLOAT3(m_camera->getPosition().x,
                              m_camera->getPosition().y - movementspeed*delta, m_camera->getPosition().z),
                     XMFLOAT3(m_camera->getTarget().x, m_camera->getTarget().y - movementspeed*delta,
                              m_camera->getTarget().z));
}

//check if pressed
if (m_keyBoardKeys[DIK_C] & 0x80)
{
    m_camera->setRotation(XMFLOAT3(m_camera->getRotation().x,
                                   m_camera->getRotation().y + movementspeed*delta/4, m_camera->getRotation().z));
}
```

This matrix get added to the shader every rendercycle and multiplys correct.

```
PS_Input VS_Main(VS_Input vertex)
{
    PS_Input vsOut = (PS_Input)0;
    float4 worldPos = mul(vertex.pos, worldMatrix); //rotation and position of the current rendered object
    vsOut.pos = mul(worldPos, viewMatrix); // camera matrix
    vsOut.pos = mul(vsOut.pos, projMatrix); // perspective projection matrix

    vsOut.tex0 = vertex.tex0;
    vsOut.norm = mul(vertex.norm, (float3x3)worldMatrix);
    vsOut.norm = normalize(vsOut.norm);

    float3 lightPos = float3(0.0f, 500.0f, 50.0f);
        vsOut.lightVec = normalize(lightPos - worldPos);

    vsOut.viewVec = normalize(cameraPos - worldPos);

    return vsOut;
}
```

**Question is: How to i get the camera moved in it's space not in the global space but still rotate it by it's axis?**

Comment: What do you mean by `move in it's space not in global space`?

Comment: In more precise terms, do you want to translate and rotate the camera in object space?

Comment: well i want to move it left if i push left. At the moment it moves left in global space not in the object space. So the translation of the camera should be depending on the rotation. Hope you understand what i mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to create a rotation matrix based on the rotation, transform the target into that rotation matrix and add that new vector to the eyes position.

Here is an example of how I do it, this will move the camera forward or back based on the delta value passed in

```
XMVECTOR Pos = XMVectorSet( this->pos.x, this->pos.y, this->pos.z, this->pos.w );
XMVECTOR At = XMVectorSet(  this->targetMagnitude.x , this->targetMagnitude.y, this->targetMagnitude.z, this->targetMagnitude.w );

XMMATRIX RotationMatrix( XMMatrixRotationRollPitchYaw( this->RadianPitch , this->RadianYaw, this->RadianRoll ));

At = XMVector3TransformCoord( At, RotationMatrix );
At = XMVector4Normalize(At);
Pos += At * delta;
XMStoreFloat4(&this->pos, Pos);
```

Comment: So i can't just rotate my LookAt matrix i need to rotate the target and create the LookAt Matrix after that? Or Cant create a looka t camera which i transforme myself?

Comment: So if you want to move relative to where you are looking at, then you need to take your look at, transform it with the rotation and then add it to the current position of where the eye is. The returned value will be the new eyes value. If you want to control how far the movement is then multiple the look at by the delta after you transform it. The code in my answer should easily work for you if you make a few edits.

Comment: so my whole thinking was wrong. i cant move it like i thought. (see the code how i move the camera i just pass in the old pos + pos change) Since i pass in global coords. I need to add functions like move left move right + an kinde of delta for the movement right? Would it be like this: http://pastebin.com/Gv6PBcKG ? What about the targetposition will be always the same?

Comment: I think i got it with your answer. I need to transform the directionvector for the camera by the current transformation of the camera. (Sure .... ) and update it by that vectors. So i changed my code to something simelar to your post. Thanks for that help !